# Is there a way to create a website without learning to web-program?

Tags: website-design

I can create an XML document without knowing XML. I use a word processor. Is there a way to do that for websites?

Comment: Yes. There are plenty of web applications that do this, such as google sites (https://sites.google.com/).

Comment: @Christofian Thanks. That looks quite interesting. But it seems that I could only edit web pages hosted by google. I'm looking for some way to create a website that I'd be able to post anywhere, so that if I get enough traffic I could actually sell ad-space on it. (Or am I wrong and google _would_ allow me to do that?)

Comment: you can add adsence to google sites.

Comment: Just keep in mind the more about programming you know, the better your website will be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to build a site without writing any HTML.

- Buy hosting space from a company that has a built in [sitebuilder](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=hosting%20with%20site%20builder&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=cee598fc631c5c56&biw=1920&bih=979&pf=p&pdl=500) tool
- Use a drag and drop (WYSIWG) HTML editor such as [Adobe's Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html) or other [freely available programs](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&cp=11&gs_id=3q&xhr=t&q=free+drag+and+drop+website+builder&pq=hosting+with+site+builder&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=free+drag+a&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=cee598fc631c5c56&biw=1920&bih=979)
- Use a free service such as [google sites](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=jotspot&passive=1209600&continue=https://sites.google.com/&followup=https://sites.google.com/) or [wordpress.com](http://wordpress.com)

All such tools have their limitations from a technical and visual point of view and most have some limitations on the type and nature of content or advertising you can add.

**Read the Terms of Service carefully** and above all make sure you **can export the content** and move it to another platform in the future when your site grows or your needs change.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment about the TOS is very important.

Answer (score 0):

You want WYSIWYG html program! There are lots of free open source applications to choose from. WYSIWG stands for What You See Is What You Get, the program usually has two view modes, a Word processing like front which is where you will add text, images, and content and lay it out as you like. Then there is the other view, which shows you the HTML codes used to render that page you just made. This makes it very easy for you to learn the syntax of HTML and get better. In fact, come to think of it, Microsoft Word is an WYSIWG program. Just go to Save As.. and choose as HTML!

Answer (score 0):

Use Adobe Muse or Weebly. These are the easiest when it comes to creating your own website. But I would suggest that you start learning HTML because sooner or later you are going to need it. If you want a little bit of extra customization then these services might not fulfill your requirements. Also you should learn the process of connecting a domain to a nameserver in order to use your custom TLD (Top Level Domain).